# Phonegap CGImageCreateWithImageProvider Error

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, xcode4.4

I recently migrated to a new mac. I needed to update my older app one last time so I downloaded an older version of Xcode and Phonegap. I get this error when I try to set the background-size css for an image.

```
CGImageCreateWithImageProvider: invalid image size: 210 x 210
```

This only happens when the app first starts up, if I try setting it after the app loads with  weinre it works correctly. What is causing this?

I saw that this error is related to the Mapview however I am not using one.

iOS 4.2.1,
Xcode 4.4.1,
Phonegap 1.6.1,
Sencha Touch 1.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested my app in the iPod Touch Safari browser and it worked. I found out that this is a problem with my older iPod Touch not being able to resize a jpg image. I changed the image to a png and it works fine now.