# CGImageCreateWithImageProvider: invalid image size: 180 x 180

Tags: ios, uiimage

I am getting the following error running my app on a device (I'm not getting it running in the simulator):

> CGImageCreateWithImageProvider`: invalid image size: 180 x 180.

```
- (IBAction)choosePic:(id)sender {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        self.imageOne = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        self.imageOne.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        self.imageOne.delegate = self;
    }
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
        self.imageOne = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        self.imageOne.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        self.imageOne.delegate = self;
    }
    [self presentViewController:self.imageOne animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us the relevant code where you create the image?

Comment: if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
          UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])                            {
    self.imageOne=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
         self.imageOne.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.imageOne.delegate=self;
     }
   
    [self presentViewController:self.imageOne
animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: add some code for reference...

Comment: You can edit your own questions to provide more information by pressing the "edit" button in the bottom left corner of the question (below the tags).

Comment: can you paste your code where u have declared property of self.imageOne  in .h file??

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387262/phonegap-cgimagecreatewithimageprovider-error) help you?

Comment: @property (nonatomic,retain) UIImagePickerController *imageOne;

Comment: @user1999186: do u synthesize this property in .m?

Comment: Satish ,i am using iOS 6.0

Answer (score 0):

As per the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387262/phonegap-cgimagecreatewithimageprovider-error)

this error can be of lower iOS version devices. As some iOS versions don't support resizing images. And also may be the problem of `JPG` image. Try with `PNG` image.